# В Opengts не добавляется в автозагрузку модуль tk10x

Tags: ubuntu, gps

С Crontab пробовал ставить после ребута и каждую минуту загрузку модуля сервера `tk10x`

> */1 * * * * vmware /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.6/bin/runserver.sh -s tk10x.

На что в логах получаю ошибку каждый раз:

> ERROR: GTS_HOME not defined .

Притом что вручную модуль стартует без проблем, т. к `$GTS_HOME` был прописан в Bash .
Та же проблема с другими методами автозагрузки (например, добавление в `init.d`).
В чём может быть причина?

Comment: *GTS_HOME был прописан* — так добавьте то же самое, например, в вызываемый файл (`/usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.6/bin/runserver.sh`).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло